# VS Code Color PIcker on mac osx hides on mouseover

Tags: visual-studio-code

When the VS Color Picker box pops up (after I hover over a color value in my .css file) it disappears immediately I move my mouse (to enter the color picker dialog box). It pops up displaying the correct color I have in the css property but it does not remain to allow me to choose a different color (or format).

I'm running Sierra and have node and NVM on my $PATH.